# Having issues with jQuery post and recieving data with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I am having some issues using jQuery to POST data to a php script. I am passing the image data from a canvas to php that will in turn save the image to the server. I am wanting this to stay as a string when sending to make it easy when the php gets it. I have tried send in json as well and no success with that. The issue is I am not getting anything in return. I have no errors in the console and php isn't leaving any errors for me either to find. I also am for the time being writing the info passed to a txt file as well to verify that data is being passed and it as well is empty. What am I doing wrong? Also I have verified the DataURL var has info in it using an alert and it contains a nice string.

```
     var dataURL = Grabcanvas.toDataURL();

     $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType : 'text',
        data: {Image:dataURL},

        success : function(data) {
        console.log("sucessfull sending:");
        console.log(data);
        },
        error : function() {
        console.log('failed');
        }
```

The php code

```
$writeDir = "dir/text/";
$upload_dir = "dir/image/";

$img = $_REQUEST['Image'];

$myfile = fopen($writeDir."newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $img . "\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);

$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = $upload_dir . mktime() . ".png";
file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it. Apparently I was explained to by a user here that `toDataURL()` is used for native javascript DOM but not jQuery DOM which I am using jQuery. So after code was rewritten to reflect this it now works correctly and sends without failing

```
    `$.ajax({
      url: 'upload.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType : 'text',
      data: {Image: $('#name of canvas')[0].toDataURL()}, //CHANGED
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,

      success: function(data) {
      console.log("sucessful send:");
      console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(d) {
      console.log('error');
      console.log(d); 
      console.log(d.responseText);
      }`
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax call you have the key as Image `{Image:dataURL}` but in your php script your trying to access image `$_REQUEST['image']`, the key is case sensitive. change the one in ajax to image

Comment: Yeah I have them set the same. I just renamed a copy items to post the code.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
var dataURL = Grabcanvas.toDataURL();
         var data = new FormData();  // added this line
         data.append('Image', dataURL);  // I have added this line
 $.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType : 'text',
    data: data,  //I have changed this

    success : function(data) {
    console.log("sucessfull sending:");
    console.log(data);
    },
    error : function() {
    console.log('failed');
    }
```

In PHP code change the following

```
$img = $_REQUEST['Image']; //you have used image, mind it it is case sensitive
```

Comment: Console throws this error with your code `TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData`